# Springboot successfully connects to mysql locally but can't connect after deploy

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, digital-ocean

I'm using mysql 5.7 on my Mac to develop a springboot app with no problems.
Here are my properties:

```
logging.level.root=WARN
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate=ERROR
server.port=8091


spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbName
spring.datasource.username=useraa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

spring.jpa.show-sql=false

spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql = false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=USERAA
```

After I deploy using `mvn clean install` and upload to my server on Digital Ocean, this error message shows when I run the .jar with command java -jar app.jar

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'useraa'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

with ERROR 28538 com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : testdb - Exception during pool initialization.
```

I checked my firewall settings already and I allow the port and I can connect to mysql using ssh/phpmyadmin with username 'useraa'. 
I also tried a CRUD command in ssh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are connecting to MySQL but it is not authenticating you.

1. Check your username and password are correct
2. Check your username has access from local host
3. Check your username has privileges to the schema

Comment: you're correct, my user name is different from my localhost